# Penalty of using QGraphicsObject vs QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, qt4

I currently have a hierarchy of items based off of QGraphicsItem.

I want to move to QGraphicsObject instead so that I can put properties on my items. I will not be making use of signals/slots or any other features of QObject.

I'm told that you shouldn't derive from QObject because it's "heavy" and "slow".

To test the impact, I derive from QGraphicsObject, add a couple properties to my items, and look at the memory usage of the running app. I create 1000 items using both flavors and I don't notice anything more than 10k more memory usage.

Since all I am adding on to my items are properties, is it safe to say that QObject only adds weight if you are using signals/slots?

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on what you mean by weight. If you're not worried about the additional memory required nor all the extra methods and things that come with `QObject`, which sound like baggage in your case, then yes.

But, if all you need is a way to store some additional information, why not subclass QGraphicsItem and add a method or two that allow you to store the necessary data?  By doing so, I think you'll better communicate the intent of your code, which seems more important than all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

How about performance? There is extra cost in QGraphicsObject when calling setX/setY, and so on. You can go to QGraphicsItemPrivate::setPosHelper and find more details.