# Qt: Signals and Slots in QGraphicsPixmapItem class

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsitem, qobject, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have inherited a class called `GraphicsPixmapItem` from `QGraphicsPixmapItem` in order to override/create some mouse events. The problem is that I want to emit a signal after some calculations are performed, but it looks like it's not possible unless some hacks are performed, since this class is not a `QObject`.

To do so, I have tried to inherit the aformentioned new class from `QObject` as well, but I keep getting compiler errors.

**My attemp:**

**Header file (`graphicspixmapitem.h`):**

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
#define GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class GraphicsPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent);
signals:
    void translationVector(QPointF info);
};

#endif // GRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM_H
```

**Source file (`graphicspixmapitem.cpp`):**

```
#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

GraphicsPixmapItem::GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent)
{

}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    //Code
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    QPointF info;
    //Code
    emit(translationVector(info));
}
```

**And I get the following linker errors:**

> undefined reference to `vtable for GraphicsPixmapItem'
>
> undefined reference to
>   `GraphicsPixmapItem::translationVector(QPointF)'

Any clue about how to proceed accordingly?

**Side note:**

I am aware that `QGraphicsObject` may be a good alternative, but as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922801/adding-signals-slots-qobject-to-qgraphicsitem-performance-hit), performance looks severely affected by the amount of signals that are emitted when operating with them, where most of them will not be used in my case. This is the reason why I prefer to create my own class with base `QGraphicsItem`, instead of `QGraphicsObject`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the meta object compiler (moc) wasn't run over the code, or that moc's result wasn't included when linking.

- Have you added graphicspixmapitem.h to qmake's `HEADERS` variable?
- Have you re-run qmake and tried a clean build in general?
- Is moc run on graphicspixmapitem.h? Check your compile log.
- Is graphicspixmapitem_moc.o included when linking? Check your compile log.

Comment: I checked previously the two first points, but it seems that the third point is not satisfied (moc is not running on graphicspixmapitem.h). How should I fix this?

Comment: The moc command is added to the Makefile by qmake. qmake scans all header files in HEADERS variable and looks for the Q_OBJECT macro there - as soon as it finds that, it should create a Makefile rule to invoke moc.

Comment: Then it looks like it is because there must be some kind of error in the code expounded above, which causes qmake not to recognize this class (header and/or source) as such. If I remove the Q_OBJECT macro, the inheritance of the QObject class and the signals, then it compiles properly, but of course it prevents me from using the signals/slots, which is precisely what I want to use ultimately in this derived class.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious wrong. If you can come up with a minimal compiling example including a .pro file, maybe someone can reproduce that on their machine and see where the problem is.

Comment: I have tested it in a separate new project, by defining the inherited class the exact same way and it compiles and links properly. Now I am even more confused. Any clue about what might be happening?

Comment: I have changed the name of the header files, renamed the class accordingly and it just compiles now. Honestly, I have no idea why was this happening, but perhaps there were some residual files related with the original name, because some days ago I created a class with the same name and I decided to delete it later, until today, when I changed my mind again. Could this fact have something to do with my issue?

Comment: Oh, I just have found it the actual reason why was this happening. I will post the answer of the question in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found out the problem involving the linkage error. In this sense, I must give my thanks to Thomas McGuire for pointing out the key idea to look for the source of the problem.

The reason is that few days ago I attempted to subclass `QGraphicsPixmapItem` (for other purposes) with the exact same name than this one, namely, `GraphicsPixmapItem` (with header file `graphicspixmapitem.h` and source file `graphicspixmapitem.cpp`).

When I did that, I finally figured out that I could do things in a different way and I no longer needed that inherited subclass, hence I removed these files from the project. But doing this is a major mistake if you do not make sure to clean the project before removing the files from the project, because the files generated by `qmake` and `moc` (`*.o`, `moc_*.cpp`, `moc_*.o`) will remain in the build/debug directory unless you remove them by hand, because they will not be deleted by cleaning the project.

Therefore, it looks like in that situation, `qmake` detects that the files already exist and it does not generate the correct ones from the updated class, causing the linking error expounded above.

In summary, if you are going to delete some files from your project, make sure to clean it previously, especially if you are going to remove a class with the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: Glad you found your problem!