# Why am I getting moc errors for QGraphicsPolygonItem reimplementation

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

Please help me! I'm on a small personal project that I needed some sort of **node editor** for. And for that I have to define the `Individual` class which inherits from the `QGraphicsPolygonItem` class. I simplified the code as much as possible to be able to identify the error but to no avail. I'm getting **MOC** (Meta Object Compiler) errors which I honestly don't understand (we're all newbies at some level). Also, there is nothing about it on the web and ***you are my last resort.***

#### Here is the `Individual` class definition:

```
#ifndef INDIVIDUAL_H
#define INDIVIDUAL_H

#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QPainterPath>

class Individual : public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Individual(QString p_fName, QString p_lName,QGraphicsItem* parent = 0);

};

#endif // INDIVIDUAL_H
```

#### And here's its implementation:

```
#include "individual.h"

Individual::Individual(QString p_fName , QString p_lNamen, QGraphicsItem* parent)
    :QGraphicsPolygonItem(parent)

{

    QPainterPath temp_path;
    temp_path.addRoundRect(0,0,100,50,10,10);
    setPolygon(temp_path.toFillPolygon());
}
```

#### And then on the main.cpp **(to be simple)** i wrote something like this:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <individual.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.setMinimumSize(800,600);
    
    QGraphicsView view(&w);
    view.setMinimumSize(800,600);
    
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    Individual myPoly("My","Name"); // The arguments are not used for now just kept them there in case
    scene.addItem(&myPoly);

    view.setScene(&scene);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### And finally the **errors** i get evrytime:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `QGraphicsPolygonItem` is a `QGraphicsItem` and it's not a `QObject`. You can use multiple inheritance feature of C++, to make the `Individual` class both of them at the same time by

```
 Individual : public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
...
```

and don't forget to call a QObject ctor for `Individual` ctore.

Now, I should recommend you to read [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922801/adding-signals-slots-qobject-to-qgraphicsitem-performance-hit) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Hope your tip will be useful for others